# Connection Refused in UDP

Tags: c, unix, udp

I am writing simple chat using UDP and I have encountered error while resending message to client. 
Error:

> sendto():: Connection refused

I have single-thread server, and multi-thread client. Two thread are running within client, writer and reader. Writer is working fine and successfully send messages to server, and server is sucessfully receving this messages. I am encountering the problem when I try to resend message.
Revelant code (server side):

```
printf("New local connection!\n");
struct sockaddr_un si_other;
char buf[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
struct msg messageReceived;
int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
rc =(int) recvfrom(localsocket,(void*)&messageReceived,sizeof(struct msg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&si_other,&len);
if(rc==-1)
{
    perror("recvfrom():");
}

rc = (int)sendto(localsocket,(void*)&messageReceived,sizeof(struct msg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&si_other,sizeof(si_other));
if(rc==-1)
{
    perror("sendto():");
}
```

Revelant code from client side:

Writer thread

```
while (fgets(messageToSend.buf, MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, stdin)!=NULL) {
    int rec = (int)sendto(sock, (void *)&messageToSend, sizeof(struct msg),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&serv,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (rec == -1) {
        printf("Error while sending to server\n");
    }
```

Reader thread

```
  printf("Reading from server initiated...\n");
int sock = (intptr_t)ptr;
struct msg receivedMessage;
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(sock,&fds);
while (1) {
    printf("Waiting..\n");
    select(sock+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(FD_ISSET(sock,&fds))
    {
        int num = (int) recvfrom(sock, (void*)&receivedMessage, sizeof(struct msg),0,NULL,0);
        if (num > 0) {
            printf("Received message:%s\n", receivedMessage.buf);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for the explicit `(void*)` cast by the way.

Comment: I don't see the initialization of 'localsocket' in your code. Here's [a nice example of the host code](http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1810/)

Comment: 'Connection refused' is a TCP error from `connect()`. You can't get it from UDP or from `sendto()`. There is something seriously wrong with this question. There is also no such thing as a 'new connection' in UDP. I suspect you have a TCP socket here, not a UDP socket.

Comment: @EJP It's apparently possible to get connection refused (as in `ECONNREFUSED`) on Linux from a `sendto` when a previous `sendto` to the same endpoint had received an ICMP delivery failure message.

Comment: @EJP: It appears that desination `localhost` is another exception.